# After installing updates in Ubuntu 12.04 the speakers have stopped working but the audio do comes from the headphones

Tags: 12.04, sound, speakers

After installing updates in Ubuntu 12.04 my speakers are not working at all but the sound is coming from the ear phones... I have tried installing things by typing various commands but it has not helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the computer with your earbuds unplugged.

Also go to sound settings with your earbuds unplugged to see what it says and take a screenshot if nothing you try fixes it by that method

If this doesn't work, try reinstalling your ALSA sound drivers:

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
```

Additionally, if using Gnome you'll probably have to do:

```
sudo apt-get install gdm ubuntu-desktop
```

Then reboot.